# Set max button space in ActionBar before overflow

Tags: android, android-actionbar

A devices with the specs of Nexus 5 shows only two button in action bar when is in portrait mode if I use `ifRoom` as attribute, the others entries are shown in overflow as action, this despite there is enough space to show at least 4 buttons

How could I set the amount of space reserved to buttons in action bar before overflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why need to set some amount of space when all you need to do is use always attribute instead of if room.
Of course this would also show limited buttons(maybe 4 at max) according to screen size.

Otherwise if you want greater control regarding spacing and all I guess your best bet would be to use your own variant of action bar. I would explain how I did that.

First of all use theme NoActionBar or hide default action bar in activity after super.onCreate method.

Then simply add a view at the top with your app icon in the corner, overflow button in right corner, and your buttons in between.

Also for Overflow menu you will have to use popUpWindow.

Comment: So If I use `always` and there isn't enough space, the extra buttons goes in overflow as action in the same way with the difference that use all space available before do this. Right?

Comment: Yes. Thats correct. Use always for all important buttons. Android will try to show as many and rest will go in overflow. And again as I said if you want greater control go the lengthy way and make your own action bar. That way you can even show 5-6 buttons but that might look ugly.